# Bootstrap NavBar collapsing in a different position

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

How do you solve this issue where the navbar menu doesn't reveal downwards on medium sizes? It works fine on other screen sizes. I attached an [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24AAr.png). I don't know what causes this, please help.

[ FIXED ]
The *md* in *col-md* apparently corresponded to its column on that particular breaking point. I thought it simply indicated what breaking point would cause it to collapse into seperate rows!

Removing the *col-md-4* and making it *col-lg-4* fixed the issue. Thank you, Overthane!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white">
  <div class="brand-column col-md-4">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
      <span>Plug</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse col-md-4" id="navbarContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto d-flex align-items-center text-nowrap text-center">
        <li class="nav-item active mx-1">
          <a class="nav-link text-header">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item mx-1">
          <a class="nav-link text-header">Solutions</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item mx-1">
          <a class="nav-link text-header">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item mx-1">
          <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm px-3 rounded-pill"> Login </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's happening because the class `.col-md-4` makes the `.navbar-collapse` element into a column with a size of 4 on medium screens (md). You should be able to achieve the desired effect by changing that element's classes to the following:

`<div class="collapse navbar-collapse col-md-12 col-lg-4" id="navbarContent">`